# Pythonのpandasでindexでマージ

Tags: python, python3, pandas

もとのデータフレームから一列だけ抜き、更にdropnaしてその後処理を施し、もとのデータフレームにマージしようと試みています。
マージキーになるようなものがデータにないため、indexを使ってマージしようと考えていますが、dropnaするとnanである部分のindexが歯抜けになるのではなく、上から0スタートで振り直されてしまいます。
これを回避する方法はないでしょうか。

詳しい方、どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: dropnaしてもindexはそのままのような気がするのですが…
実際に書いているコードを質問につけていただけると回答しやすいかなと思います。

Comment: 別環境で試したところ確かにindexはそのままになりました。。。
もとのコードを回収して報告させていただきますのでしばらくお待ち下さい。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

マージの方法は数種類あり、以下のように使い分けられます。

1. **pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)**: inner join
2. **df1.join(df2)**: left join
3. **pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)**: outer join

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468069/merge-two-dataframes-by-index

当然、outer joinを使えば、欠損値部分は再び欠損値になります。inner joinを使えば、もとのデータに存在している行のうち、dropnaした側に存在しないindexの行は消えます。

そのため、現実的には「再びマージする」のような処理を加えるよりは、以下を実行したほうが良いです:

```py
df.dropna(subset=["欠損値を見る列名"])
```

### サンプルの実行

[test.csv]

```
c1,c2
1,1
2,
3,5
```

[ipythonでの実行]

> もとのデータフレームから一列だけ抜き、更にdropnaしてその後処理を施し、もとのデータフレームにマージしようと試みています。

これを以下で実行します。

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

In [3]: df[["c2"]].dropna()
Out[3]:
    c2
0  1.0
2  5.0

In [4]: df2 = df[["c2"]].dropna()

In [5]: df1 = df[["c1"]]

In [6]: pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
Out[6]:
   c1   c2
0   1  1.0
2   3  5.0

In [7]: df1.join(df2)
Out[7]:
   c1   c2
0   1  1.0
1   2  NaN
2   3  5.0

In [8]: df2.join(df1)
Out[8]:
    c2  c1
0  1.0   1
2  5.0   3

In [9]: pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)
Out[9]:
   c1   c2
0   1  1.0
1   2  NaN
2   3  5.0

In[10]: df.dropna(subset=["c2"])
Out[10]:
   c1   c2
0   1  1.0
2   3  5.0


In [11]: df.dropna(subset=["c1"])
Out[11]:
   c1   c2
0   1  1.0
1   2  NaN
2   3  5.0
```